# Is there any way to import a component by route name into another component in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need to import a vue js component page into another component by route name.
Anyone can show me the solution.
for example

```
{ path: '/dashboardadmin', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default, name: 'AdminDashboard' }
```

this is one of my vue route. I have to import this component into another component by the name AdminDashboard

like this

```
import AdminDashboard from '*route name*';
```

Anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if your parent component is `A.vue` and the component that you want to import in `A.vue` is like `B.vue` then you have to only import your `B.vue` into `A.vue` like this

`import B from './B.vue'` and use it into export default

```
export default {
  components: {
    B
  },
}
```

simple

Comment: ok, thanks for your replay...
this is not am looking. What i mean is i need import 'B' by whatever the name attribute for 'B' component route
like this 
{ path: '/b', component: require('./components/B.vue').default, name: 'bcomponent' }
import B from 'bcomponent';